# VirtualBox install

Tags: 12.10, virtualbox, virtualization

I am using Win 7 Ultimate. I have the current version of Virtualbox. I downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 from the Ubuntu website and the install as disc image.

Ubuntu probably goes thru about 75% of the install and then I get an error message saying that there is a hardware issue and cannot continue. The error message also says it cannot read the disc, etc, etc.

I have downloaded 2 different versions of Ubuntu. I had downloaded and re-installed VirtualBox twice. I also tried 12.04 but came into the same issue. I downloaded the "desktop AMD-64" Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you haven't enabled the Virtualization Technology through your BIOS. I cannot help you with that because every one is different.

Try downloading the 32-bit version of Ubuntu.
Hope it helps you.

Comment: Like Ivar Snel said, you should also check that the VM settings are correct you can do this using the Settings button on the main screen.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the virtual disk has enough free space for installation of Ubuntu.

I believe Ubuntu Desktop edition needs at least 5Gb free space.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable PAE/NX and VT-x or AMD-V
BUT... Something strange happened in VMware.
Whren I enable VT-x there...
VT-x is not supported in ths VM.
Continue without VT-x? 
(Or something like that, I don't concentrate (Forget))

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you [check the md5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) for the ISO that you download. This simple check can save you hours of frustration.

It does sound like it might be a 64bit virtualisation problem however.  Download the 32bit (i386) release, check the md5sum as mentioned, and try installing that.